# Execução de macro é interrompida repetidamente - Como evitar?

Tags: vba

Quando estou executando uma macro VBA, eventualmente o código é interrompido, como se houvesse `breakpoints`.

A mensagem exibida é:

> A execução do código foi interrompida.

Se aceitar a mensagem e continuar a execução do código, o comportamento se repete se a macro for longa (procedimento com muitas linhas ou laços longos).

A interrupção acontece em diversos locais.

Como posso evitar/resolver esse comportamento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque o VBA tratou incorretamente um `breakpoint` que foi removido, ou (mais frequente) um `breakpoint` que estava em um trecho de código que foi removido ou movido.

Infelizmente não lembro onde descobri a solução, e é um *hack* feio, mas que resolve.

1. Aceite a mensagem de interrupção do código.
2. Clique no item de menu `depurar` ou `debug` (só clique para abrir o menu).
3. Pressione `control+Break (ou pause)` **duas vezes**.

Continue a execução da macro.